# “zero placeholder” for working counter as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

**How do make a zero placeholder for the counter?**

My thought was an "if" condition with greater
and lesser would work.

```
if count is more than .00 and less than 10.00, add "0000000" etc.
```

[alt text http://www.ashcraftband.com/myspace/videodnd/icon_3.jpg](http://www.ashcraftband.com/myspace/videodnd/icon_3.jpg)

**CODE** "from some of the best minds"

```
//counts
var timer:Timer = new Timer(10);   
var count:int = 0; //start at -1 if you want the first decimal to be 0   
var fcount:int = 0;  

timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, incrementCounter);   
timer.start();   


function incrementCounter(event:TimerEvent) {  
  count++;  

  var whole_value:int = int(count / 100); //change value 
  var tenths:int = int(count / 10) % 10;   
  var hundredths:int = int(count) % 10;   

  mytext.text = whole_value + " : " + tenths + hundredths;  
} 

///////////////////////////////////////////////

//counts and accelerates
//CA, NC, LONDON "increments"
var timer:Timer = new Timer(10);  
var count:int = 0; //start at -1 if you want the first decimal to be 0  
var fcount:int = 0; 

timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, incrementCounter);  
timer.start();  

function incrementCounter(event:TimerEvent) {  
  count++;  
  //
  fcount=int(count*count/10000);//starts out slow... then speeds up 
  //
  var whole_value:int = int(fcount / 100); //change value 
  var tenths:int = int(fcount / 10) % 10;   
  var hundredths:int = int(fcount) % 10;   

  mytext.text = whole_value + " : " + tenths + hundredths;  
}
```

[alt text http://www.ashcraftband.com/myspace/videodnd/icon-3.jpg](http://www.ashcraftband.com/myspace/videodnd/icon-3.jpg)

***I makes zeros...eeeeerrrrrrr...not animation, don't laugh!***
***curses***

```
var timer:Timer = new Timer(10);  
var count:int = 0; //start at -1 if you want the first decimal to be 0  
var fcount:int = 0; 

timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, incrementCounter);  
timer.start();  

function incrementCounter(event:TimerEvent) {  
  count++;  
  //
  fcount=int(count*count/10000);//starts out slow... then speeds up 
  //
  var whole_value:int = int(fcount / 100); //change value 
  var tenths:int = int(fcount / 10) % 10;   
  var hundredths:int = int(fcount) % 10;   
////////////// 
 function formatCount(i:int):String { 

    var fraction:int = i % 100; 
    var whole:int = i / 100; 

    return ("0000000" + whole).substr(-7, 7) + "." + (fraction < 10 ? "0" : "") + fraction; 
} 

function test():void { 
    for (var i:int = 1; i<100000; i += 3) { 
        trace(i + " -> " + formatCount(i)); 
    } 
} 
//////////////
mytext.text = formatCount(whole_value + " : " + tenths + hundredths); 

 // mytext.text = whole_value + " : " + tenths + hundredths;  
}
```

"thanks for the help guys"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function to format it the way you want.

```
function formatCount(i:int):String {

    var fraction:int = i % 100;
    var whole:int = i / 100;

    return ("0000000" + whole).substr(-7, 7) + "." + (fraction < 10 ? "0" : "") + fraction;
}

function test():void {
    for (var i:int = 1; i<100000; i += 3) {
        trace(i + " -> " + formatCount(i));
    }
}
]]>
```

Sample output (spacing added):

```
1     -> 0000000.01
4     -> 0000000.04
7     -> 0000000.07
10    -> 0000000.10
13    -> 0000000.13
97    -> 0000000.97
100   -> 0000001.00
103   -> 0000001.03
235   -> 0000002.35
520   -> 0000005.20
997   -> 0000009.97
1000  -> 0000010.00
1003  -> 0000010.03
99997 -> 0000999.97
```

Comment: Not sure how to apply it, almost out of noobsville. The output show no errors, yet it didn't display. Probally me.

Comment: You'd do something like: `myTextBox.text = formatCount(score);`

Comment: That makes sense, but I broke it. See above

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you need to do that yourself:

Here's some [code](http://etutorials.org/Programming/actionscript/Part+I+Local+Recipes/Chapter+5.+Numbers+and+Math/Recipe+5.4+Inserting+Leading+or+Trailing+Zeros/).

Answer (score 0):

here is a quick example, it is pretty straight forward, but let me know if you have any questions.

```
var n:Number = 999.99123;
var minLength:int = 15;
var s:String = n.toFixed(2);
var diff:int = minLength - s.length;

while (diff > 0) {
    s = '0' + s;
    diff--;
}

trace(s);
```

**EDIT:** did you want "tenths" to always be 0?

Comment: I tested this code and it did not produce the results the OP asked for.  I got results like `3 -> 000000000003.00` and `153 -> 000000000153.00` but it should be `3 -> 0000000.03` and `153 -> 0000001.53`

Comment: This example will format a Number (ie floating point) to 2 decimal places... however VideoDnd's count variable is an integer (which equates to 1/100ths of a second). You could fix this by changing the first line to: var n:Number = count/100;

Answer (score 0):

**MILLIONS COUNTER WITH ZERO PLACEHOLDERS**

```
//CA, NC, LONDON, ED, GA "increments"
var timer:Timer = new Timer(10);  
var count:int = 0; //start at -1 if you want the first decimal to be 0  
var fcount:int = 0; 

timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, incrementCounter);  
timer.start();  

function incrementCounter(event:TimerEvent) {  
  count++;  
  fcount=int(count*count/10000);//starts out slow... then speeds up 
  mytext.text = formatCount(fcount);
}

function formatCount(i:int):String { 
     var fraction:int = i % 100; 
     var whole:int = i / 100;  

    return ("0000000" + whole).substr(-7, 7) + "." + (fraction < 10 ? "0" + fraction : fraction); 
}
```